# How to convert from HTML to UTF-8 in java

Tags: java, html, utf-8

I have an ASCII String, with HTML entities, like:

```
 &agrave;
 &uml;
 &ccedil;
```

I need this String to be without those entities and convert them into UTF-8 chars.
Is there any easy way, in java to do that?

Where:

```
 Clazz.method("a&agrave;","UTF-8")
```

returns "aà"

or something like that?

Comment: You mean instead of 'à' you have &agrave; ?  For example instead of *"c'est-à-dire"* you have *"c'est-&agrave;-dire"*?   (you know that ASCII defines only 128 codepoints right? 'à' is **not** an ASCII character)

Comment: ok, I edited your post to see that it was an encoding issue in your question.

Comment: The way you ask the question is a bit strange, because HTML and UTF-8 are two totally different things - HTML is a file format while UTF-8 is a character encoding. HTML files have a character encoding, i.e. you can have an HTML file that's UTF-8 encoded, ISO-8859-1 encoded etc.

Comment: Hi Jesper. I have HTML (only ASCII chars) and I want it in plain text. There may be accents, so an encoding must be chosen. And I need UTF-8.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).  Apparently it understands all character entities defined in HTML 4.

Comment: 2021 update: `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` has been [deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) in favor of Commons Text [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html).