# Convert HTML character code to char in Java

Tags: java, html, encoding, utf-8

Our XML feed gives us encoded UTF-8 characters inside ISO-8859-1 a file. This is being fed into the database. So the text is ISO-8859-1 encoded and contains following stuff:

```
&#x91d1;&#x878d;&#x5e02;&#x573a;
```

Is there a way to convert that into a normal Java string? Similar to:

```
String str = fromHtmlUtf8("&#x91d1;&#x878d;&#x5e02;&#x573a;");
```

Where resulting str will contain normal UTF8 chars. Chinese in this case, but can be quite mixed.

Thanks.

Comment: I like this solution: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/599671/1392882>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons:
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

next time search before: [How to convert from HTML to UTF-8 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825985/how-to-convert-from-html-to-utf-8-in-java/2826064#2826064)

Comment: Great people think alike. I was looking at that same page literally just now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need small lib for this, you can use HTMLEntitles

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=htmlentities