# How to convert UTF-8 to its corresponding languages in android

Tags: android

I am getting a code **& #2384; & #2344;& #2350; & #2307; & #2358;& #2367;& #2357;& #2366;& #2351;**(ॐ नमः शिवाय) from web-server.

How to convert it into hindi , telugu , tamil , kanada and etc in android

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669457/convert-html-character-code-to-char-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML entities. Use `Html.fromHtml()`:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("& #2384; & #2344;..."));
```

Comment: Hay, It is not working in some devices. Mainly in HTC mobiles. Can you please help me?