# How to convert HTML entities in Java

Tags: java, html, encoding

I got some strings like `B&#236;nh Định`, `C&#224; Mau` (which supposed to be "Bình Định", "Cà Mau") what should I do to print them out as "Bình Định", "Cà mau"?

I got those strings from a html website, I just want to write them as "Bình Định", "Cà Mau" into a text file.

Comment: Interesting question... HTML parsers can certainly turn entities into UTF-8, but requiring an HTML parser to do _that_ is probably overkill

Comment: Well i got those strings from a html website, I just want to write them as "Bình Định", "Cà Mau" into a text file.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825985/how-to-convert-from-html-to-utf-8-in-java

Comment: @PabloLozano irrelevant, not everybody uses apache-commons

Comment: Why don't you save the text file with an encoding of UTF-8? That way it will preserve the special characters.

Comment: @fge He asked for a solution and I'm suggesting him to use that library to solve his problem

Comment: @adarshr the problem is that some of these characters are HTML-escaped entities

Comment: OK, so, `Character.codePointAt("Bình Định", 1)` _does_ return 236 -- but I can't manage to do the reverse :(

Comment: @PabloLozano I need this to do my homework, it won't be good if my teacher doesn't have that library.

Comment: @adarshr I tried create a .txt file with those word, then save it with UTF-8 encoding, it's still &#236

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
int target = 236;
char[] unicodeCharPair = Character.toChars(target);
System.out.println("Char: " + new String(unicodeCharPair));
// Char: ì
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve but failed to do! Brilliant! +1

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you very much, I love you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getBytes()` method for your coded format

Comment: Could you make it more detailed? How do I used this?

I tried:

         String Str1 = "B&#236;nh Định";

         byte[] Str2 = Str1.getBytes();

         System.out.println("Returned  Value " + Str2 );

         Str2 = Str1.getBytes( "UTF-8" );

         System.out.println("Returned  Value " + Str2 );

But don't understand what was printed.

Comment: would you explain a bit more? this answer makes no sense to me as it is

Comment: This problem cannot be solved in that way, HTML entities are the way HTML escape special characters. What he needs is a HTML-to-plain text conversion. By the way, there is no way in Java standard API to do so. Another link with same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825985/how-to-convert-from-html-to-utf-8-in-java

Comment: @PabloLozano that may be true for HTML entity names, but numeric notation matches code points so this should be just a matter of converting a code point to a character