# Java code to convert HEX strings &#x to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to write a java tool to convert HEX encoded (honestly I don’t know what sort of encoding is this) string to UTF-8 string.  Can someone point me into the right direction or help me with the piece of code which does the conversion. While searching the web, I found out that PHP has a utility method htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE); which does this conversion. I couldn’t find a java equivalent of it. Btw, the language is greek.

String:

```
&#x394;&#x3B5;&#x3BD; &#x3BC;&#x3BF;&#x3C5; &#x3AC;&#x3C1;&#x3B5;&#x3C3;&#x3B5; &#x3BA;&#x3B1;&#x3B8;&#x3CC;&#x3BB;&#x3BF;&#x3C5;
```

Expected Result : Δεν μου άρεσε καθόλου

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you even checked SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825985/how-to-convert-from-html-to-utf-8-in-java